# How to programatically change an attribute of widget created by a LayoutInflater?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, layout-inflater

I want to access the child of a widget created by a LayoutInflater in order to change the text displayed by a TextView inside it.
How could I do this?
I've made a diagram to explain.

```
LinearLayout
--->LayoutInflater

    ---->LinearLayout
         ---->LinearLayout
              ---->TextView
              ---->TextView
    ---->LinearLayout
         ---->LinearLayout
              ---->TextView
              ---->TextView
    ---->LinearLayout
         ---->LinearLayout
              ---->TextView
              ---->TextView
etc
```

I want to be able to access each individual TextView and change it's attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the TextViews and change it's attributes through the `View` returned by the inflater.

I assume you have something like this:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
```

Then you can access the resources like this:

```
TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text.setText("Hello");
```

Comment: So findViewById only returns the children of the view from which it is called?